# What is the anchor view ID in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout

I am learning Android Studio and I was reading about anchor view ID, The documentation didn't give any further information and I was curious to have some guidance on this matter.
All They mentioned is that it can be appended as a parameter to the android:layout_below or any other layout alignment attributes in the Relative Layout

Comment: "I was reading about anchor view ID" -- where? "it can be appended as a parameter to the android:layout_below or any other layout alignment attributes in the Relative Layout" -- `RelativeLayout` has generally been replaced by `ConstraintLayout`. Both have the concept of placing children of the layout relative to other children in the layout. Attributes like `android:layout_below` on `RelativeLayout` identify the other widget for the constraint ("this one is to be below that one"). Presumably, "anchor view ID" is simply the ID of the widget representing the other end of this constraint.

Answer (score 1):

By "anchor" it is meant, that your view will be positioned relatively to another view called "anchor view". For example, 
`android:layout_below="@id/anchor_view"`
means, that your view will be positioned below view with id "@id/anchor_view".